# The meaning of “Trolling around”

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

From [*Programming Entity Framework: DbContext*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022237.do) by Julia Lerman, page 6:

> Avoiding trolling around the guts of Entity Framework

What does "trolling around" mean in this fragment? Entity Framework is the name of a framework for programming.

Comment: See the definition of [*troll*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/troll--2?q=trolling#troll--2__2) ("carefully and systematically search an area for something").

Comment: Are you just trolling around Stackexchange? ;)

Answer (score 6):

In this case, Trolling is used in the fishing sense:

[Trolling (fishing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolling_%28fishing%29)

> **Trolling** is a method of fishing where one or more fishing lines, baited with lures or bait fish, are drawn through the water. This may
>   be behind a moving boat, or by slowly winding the line in when fishing
>   from a static position, or even sweeping the line from side-to-side,
>   e.g. when fishing from a jetty.

The original author is attempting to convey that they are trying to avoid going over all of the details of the entire framework, including details that are trivial to most people.

FYI, some people will also use **[Trawling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trawling)** in the same manner and context.

Comment: I venture to suggest that in OP's specific context, ***most*** people would use *trawling*, rather than *trolling*.

Comment: I can vouch for "trolling" and related terms such as "trolling motor" all over the US Midwest. Google [ trolling motor ]. "Trawling" on the other hand is fishing with a net, not with baited lines.

Comment: "In this case, *trolling* is used in the fishing sense." Do you mean there are cases in which it *isn't* used in that sense?

Comment: @MετάEd I'm not sure if you're kidding or not, so here's a link to a definition of Internet Trolling : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_(Internet)

Comment: @Zoot And if you read that article, you know it points out that it's the same term being used figuratively. There really is no trolling other than either (real) or (figurative) fishing for a bite.

Comment: @MετάEd The article also points out the the Old Norse word for a mythological monster, where they are often creatures bent on mischief and wickedness.  Internet trolls seem to be the at the intersection of the two words, rather than simply being from fishing term.

Comment: @Zoot In the context of "Internet trolling" (a misnomer, as Usenet long predated the Internet), the verb "troll" (meaning to fish) came first and had nothing to do with the monster. After the verb became prevalent, the noun appeared and of course did refer not just to fishing but also to the monster. The person who trolls (fishes) was characterized, metaphorically speaking, as a troll (monster) – a play on words. This is clear not only from the Wikipedia article but also the historical record, plus my own personal history on Usenet backs it up. In short, the verb is a fishing term.

Answer (score 2):

Trolling is a method of fishing from a moving boat by dragging a lure or bait of some sort. It is a somewhat random method of fishing. Even if you know your lure can catch the fish you are after, and you know the fish you are trying to catch are actually present somewhere in the water your boat is moving through, you do not know exactly where the fish are.

In this context, the author does not want anyone changing code in the entity framework in hope of fixing some problem *unless that person knows exactly what code to change*.

Answer (score 0):

*Trolling around* means walking around looking to be invited to something or just running about from place to place looking for a donation and having a sly expression.